# Statistical Mechanics Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

While i was doing my homework on statistical mechanics, i saw this:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\beta(ax^2-bx^3+cx^4)}dx$.

So, $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, $c$ can be anything.
Also, $b$ and $c$ are small numbers.

What is the method to solve this problem?

Comment: A closed solution in terms of well-known functions seems very unlikely except when $a, b, c$ satisfy a very specific relation. But if $b$ and $c$ may be regarded as perturbations, then we may extract some asymptotic formula.

Comment: You cannot reduce $x^2(ax^2+bx+c)\ $ to $\(x+d)^4 \ $ because the latter will have a constant and x term whereas the former won’t